# Master/slave Job architectural design in spring batch using modular job approach

Tags: java, spring, architecture, spring-batch, batch-processing

I hope you're doing great.
I'm facing design problem in spring batch.

Let me explain:

**I have a modular spring batch job architecture,
each job has its own config file et context.
I am designing a master Job to launch the subjobs (50+ types of subjobs).**

***X obj has among other name, state and blob which contains the csv file attached to it.
X obj will be updated after being processed.***
I follow the first approach of fetching all X obj and then looping (in java stream) to call the appropriate job.

But this approach has a lot of limitations.

**So I design a masterJob with reader processor and writer.**

*MasterJob should read X obj and call the appropriate subJob and the update the state of X obj.*

masterJobReader which call a custom service to get a list of let's say X obj.

I started by trying to launch subjob from within the masterJob processor but It did not work.

I did some research and I find that JobStep could be more adequate for this scenario.

**But I'm stuck with how to pass the item read by masterJobReader to JobStep has parameter.**

**I did saw DefaultJobParameterExtractor and I try to set the Item read into the stepExecutionContext but It's not working.**

> My question how to pass parameter from MasterJob to SubJob using
> JobStep approach?

If there is better way to deal with this then I'm all yours!

**I'm using Java Config and spring batch 4.3.**

Edit to provide sample code:

```
@Configuration
public class MasterJob {

@Value("${defaultCompletionPolicy}")
private Integer defaultCompletionPolicy;

@Autowired
protected StepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory;

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterJob.class);

@Autowired
protected JobRepository jobRepo;

@Autowired
protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("JOB_NAME1")
private Job JOB_NAME1; // this should change to be dynamic as there are around 50 types of job

@Bean(name = "masterJob")
protected Job masterBatchJob() throws ApiException {

    return new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepo).get("masterJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(masterJobStep(masterJobReader(), masterJobWriter()))
            .next(jobStepJobStep1(null))
            .next(masterUpdateStep()) // update the state of objX
            .build();
}



@Bean(name = "masterJobStep")
protected Step masterJobStep(@Qualifier("masterJobReader") MasterJobReader masterReader,
        @Qualifier("masterJobWriter") MasterJobWriter masterWriter) throws ApiException {
    
    logger.debug("inside   masterJobStep");

    return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterJobStep")

            .<Customer, Customer>chunk(defaultCompletionPolicy)
            .reader(masterJobReader())
            .processor(masterJobProcessor())
            .writer(masterJobWriter())
            .transactionManager(transactionManager)             
            .listener(new MasterJobWriter()) // I set the parameter inside this.
            .listener(masterPromotionListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "masterJobWriter", destroyMethod = "")
@StepScope
protected MasterJobWriter masterJobWriter() {
    return new MasterJobWriter();
}

@Bean(name = "masterJobReader", destroyMethod = "")
@StepScope
protected MasterJobReader masterJobReader() throws ApiException {
    return new MasterJobReader();
}


protected FieldSetMapper<Customer> mapper() {
    return new CustomerMapper();
}

@Bean(name="masterPromotionListener")
public ExecutionContextPromotionListener masterPromotionListener() {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    
    listener.setKeys(
             
            new String[]                        
                    {   
                        "inputFile", 
                        "outputFile", 
                        "customerId",                           
                        "comments", 
                        "customer" 
                    });
    
    //listener.setStrict(true);
    return listener;
}



@Bean(name = "masterUpdateStep")
public Step masterUpdateStep() {

    return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterCleanStep").tasklet(new MasterUpdateTasklet()).build();
}



@Bean(name = "masterJobProcessor", destroyMethod = "")
@StepScope
protected MasterJobProcessor masterJobProcessor() {
    return new MasterJobProcessor();
}


@Bean
public Step jobStepJobStep1(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("jobStepJobStep1")
                .job(JOB_NAME1)
                .launcher(jobLauncher)
                .parametersExtractor(jobParametersExtractor())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public DefaultJobParametersExtractor jobParametersExtractor() {
    DefaultJobParametersExtractor extractor = new DefaultJobParametersExtractor();

    extractor.setKeys(
            new String[] { "inputFile", "outputFile", , "customerId", "comments", "customer" });

    return extractor;
}
 }
```

This is how I set parameter from within the **MasterJobWriter**:

```
String inputFile = fetchInputFile(customer);
                String outputFile = buildOutputFileName(customer);
                
               Comments comments = "comments"; // from business logic
                
                ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
                stepContext.put("inputFile", inputFile);
                stepContext.put("outputFile", outputFile);                 
                stepContext.put("customerId", customer.getCustomerId());
                stepContext.put("comments", new CustomJobParameter<Comments>(comments));
                stepContext.put("customer", new CustomJobParameter<Customer>(customer));
```

I follow [this section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#external-flows) of spring batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question how to pass parameter from MasterJob to SubJob using JobStep approach?

The [JobParametersExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobParametersExtractor.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to extract parameters from the main job and pass them to the subjob. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/jobStepSample.xml).

EDIT: Adding suggestions based on comments

> I have a list of X obj in the DB. X obj has among other fields, id, type(of work), name, state and blob which contains the csv file attached to it. The blob field containing the csv file depends on the type field so it's not one pattern csv file. I need to process each X obj and save the content of the csv file in the DB and generate a csv result file containing the original data plus a comment field in the result csv file and update X obj state with the result csv field attached to X obj and other fields.

As you can see, the process is already complex for a single X object. So trying to process all X objects in the same job of jobs is too complex IMHO. [So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things..](https://twitter.com/codewisdom/status/1006219510741983232)

> If there is better way to deal with this then I'm all yours!

Since you are open for suggestions, I will recommend two options:

**Option 1:**

If it were up to me, I would create a job instance per X obj. This way, I can 1) parallelize things and 2) in case of failure, restart only the failed job. These two characteristics (Scalability and Restartability)  are almost impossible with the job of jobs approach. Even if you have a lot of X objects, this is not a problem. You can use one of the scaling techniques provided by Spring Batch to process things in parallel.

**Option 2:**

If you really can't or don't want to use different job instances, you can  use a single job with a chunk-oriented step that iterates over X objects list. The processing logic seems independent from one record to another, so this step should be easily scalable with multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this already but It's not working

Comment: This is exception thrown by the subjob as it's not receiving the parameter from (csv) from the masterJob: Factory method 'csvReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be null

Comment: In your description you said it's working: `I did saw DefaultJobParameterExtractor and I try to set the Item read into the stepExecutionContext but It's working.`. did you mean it's **not** working? The way to pass parameters from the main job to sub jobs is through JobParametersExctractor as mentioned in the answer. This `Path must not be null` error seems not related to the original issue, so please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine for your feedback, I'll update the question

Comment: I've provided sample code for the masterJob

Comment: Thanks for the update. `If there is better way to deal with this then I'm all yours!`: Can you describe your requirement without referring to Spring Batch? What the input/output of your process?

Comment: I have a list of X obj  in the DB. 
X obj has among other fields, id, type(of work),  name, state and blob which contains the csv file attached to it.
The blob field containing the csv file depends on the type field so it's not one pattern csv file.
I need to process each X obj and save the content of the csv file in the DB and generate a csv  result  file containing the original data plus a comment field in the result csv file and update X obj state with the result csv field attached to  X obj and other fields.

Comment: That's why I created subjobs for each type work in a modular way so that the master job only get all X obj to be launch and delegates to subjob to do the actual processing and finally masterJob update the state of X obj

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple suggestions. Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by job instance in the first option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231779/discussion-between-kourouma-coder-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).